# Remove the button that have no text

Tags: javascript, loops, button, fetch-api

Source Github API :

```
https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js/issues
```

I made 3 button here which is :

```
const html = test
        .map((user) => {
          return `
            <ul id="myUL">
              <div style="min-height: 50px;">
                <div class="card card-body" style="width: 100%;">
                  <li><a href="#">
                  ${user.title}
                  <button>
                  ${user.labels
                    .map((label, index) => {
                      if (index === 0) {
                        return `${label.name}`;
                      }
                    })
                    .join("")}
                  </button>
                  <button>
                  ${user.labels
                    .map((label, index) => {
                      if (index === 1) {
                        return `${label.name}`;
                      }
                    })
                    .join("")}
                  </button>
                  <button>
                  ${user.labels
                    .map((label, index) => {
                      if (index === 2) {
                        return `${label.name}`;
                      }
                    })
                    .join("")}
                  </button>
                  </a></li>  
                </div>
              </div>
          </ul>
          `;
        })
        .join("");
      console.log(html);
      document.querySelector("#app").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I tried using this code :

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll("button");

button.forEach(function (button) {
  if (!button.value) {
    button.remove();
  }
});
```

Some of the data from API (labels > name) have empty text so all it show is an empty button without text. And I want to remove all button that doesn't have any text on it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you using next.js, or is this vanilla JS? If you're using next.js, you should add that tag

Comment: Actually I don't really know if I'm using next.js or not. I think im using Vanilla JS. The next.js that mentioned from the source is only the data. Other than that I just use map looping which I think its Vanilla JS. Though I might be wrong

Comment: If you want the buttons that have no text or content, you need to check its `textContent` or `innerHTML` property, not its `value` property, since you don't appear to be setting that attribute in your function.

Comment: The GitHub URL does not appear to be relevant to the question; I'd remove it.

Comment: so if the button don't have text, that's mean the ```textContent``` is none right? I tried other way like if the ```textContent``` is empty, then i add ```remove()``` on it. But still can't work.

Comment: It can be done via css, but i dont think its the right aproach... are you rendering buttons just to be removed after? Why you dont just loop through existent `user.labels` and then render the buttons?

Comment: there's user 1 that have like 1 labels only, then user 2 have 3 labels. So when when it display user 2, all 3 button show up with existing ```textContent``` while user 1 only show up 1 button with ```textContent``` while the other 2 only have button with empty content